# ATNA validator formatting error '^.+?\^\^\^.*?&amp;.+?&amp;ISO$'

Tags: regex

Getting an error on the validation of my MRN format.

```
Test every $partid in /AuditMessage/ParticipantObjectIdentification[@ParticipantObjectTypeCode='1' and @ParticipantObjectTypeCodeRole='1'] satisfies not($partid/@ParticipantObjectID) or matches($partid/@ParticipantObjectID,'^.+?\^\^\^.*?&amp;.+?&amp;ISO$')
Description Patient/@ParticipantObjectID must have this form '^.+?\^\^\^.*?&amp;.+?&amp;ISO$' if Patient/@ParticipantObjectID present ( IHE IT Infrastructure Technical Framework, Volume 2b, Rev 10.0 , 3.47.5.1.1 )
```

Here is the string in question. The validator does not seem to like my MRN.

```
<ParticipantObjectIdentification ParticipantObjectID="158354^^^&amp;2.16.840.1.113883.3.1230.1.51.1.1&amp;ISO" ParticipantObjectTypeCode="1" ParticipantObjectTypeCodeRole="1">
```

The regex looks good to me. Can anyone see whats wrong here?

Comment: `&` vs `&amp;`? If the validator runs on that entity-encoded string exactly then it's not going to match

Comment: @Crazysheep &amp; I think stack overflow ripped that out when it rendered the page.

Comment: Regex seems fine, also works on http://regex101.com. Maybe the issue is somewhere else other than the regex.